# how to write route better in node express framework

Tags: node.js, express

I am using the node express framework, as my project has more and more routes,in my app.js,the code is :

```
var routeA=require('./routes/api/a');
var routeB=require('./routes/api/b');
var routeC=require('./routes/api/c');
```

and the 'app.use' code is:

```
app.use('/api/a',routeA);
app.use('/api/b',routeB);
app.use('/api/c',routec);
```

Whether has a less code ? like this:

```
var routeApiArr=require('./routes/api/*');// Array
app.use('/api/*',routeApiArr);
```

I do not know whether it can work.

Or have a better function? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this in your app.js :

```
function loadRoutes(app) {
    var routesDir = './app/routes/';
    var fs = require('fs');
    fs.readdir(routesDir, function(err, routes) {
        routes.forEach(function(route) {
            require(routesDir + route)(app);
        });
    });
}
```

Then you can write your routes as:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    issueManagement(app);
};

function issueManagement(app) {


    //Find issues...
    app.get('/find/issues', function(req, res) {
        // issuesService.findIssues(function);
    });
}
```